Connection issues between Mongodb and Vercel Node.js Server
I am running into some strange issues with the connection between my vercel node.js server and mongodb collection. I have integrated vercel and mongodb while also having an environment variable for my node.js connection to mongodb. This has resulted in a MONGODB_URI in this format (mongodb+srv://vercel-admin-user) created by vercel and a MONGO_URL in this format (mongodb+srv://myusername) which I created. Right now I am pointing to MONGO_URL, but I have tried pointing to the other and still got the same issue. The issue is that when I redeploy my website when I make changes (that have nothing to do with my db connection) it gives me errors connecting to my db.These errors are either timeout errors or that my ip isn't whitelisted, which it is. Then after a while randomly the db will connect. This is how I connect to my db in my index.js file:
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URL;

console.log("mongo: " + mongoUri);

// Mongoose connection management
let conn = null;

export async function connect() {
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = mongoose
      .connect(mongoUri, {
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
      })
      .then(() => mongoose);

    // `await`ing connection after assigning to the `conn` variable
    // to avoid multiple function calls creating new connections
    await conn;
  }

  return conn;
}

connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected successfully");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Database connection failed:", err);
  });

Is there anything I am missing because it seems like at any moment the connection will fail, which means I have to constantly monitor it. Thanks
When the error occurs I try redeploying, re-whitelisting my ip in mongodb, and just leaving the website for a bit. None of these instantly fix the problem and don't result in helpful errors. The whole issue is very random, which is why it is so frustrating
